# How can the integrity of Debian's debian-keyring package be verified?

Tags: debian, apt

I encountered a Debian machine that, when trying to update packages, threw the widely discussed "GPG error: http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553". In oder to import the current keys, the package debian-keyring needs to be installed.

But since the keys on the machine are no longer valid, how can I be sure that the packet's contents have not been tampered with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rule out adding the key and using that, you can still verify the MD5 manually.

```
Print the md5sum of the Packages file which is listed in the Release file.
sed -n "s,main/binary-i386/Packages$,,p" ftp.us.debian.org_debian_dists_sid_Release 
# Print the md5sum of the Packages file itself.
md5sum ftp.us.debian.org_debian_dists_sid_main_binary-i386_Packages
```

Finally, check the MD5 or SHA checksum of the package itself:

```
apt-cache show <package_name> | sed -n "s/MD5sum: //p" # Grab the checksum from the APT cache.
md5sum <binary_package_name>.deb                       # Compare it against the binary package's checksum.
```

[Source](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_manually_check_for_package.27s_integrity)